# Image outside container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to set position on image to be about half inside and outside Bootstrap container.

I have Bootstrap Container with ROW inside, inside all that I have `COL-MD-8` with `PULL-RIGHT` class. it works OK. Now I want to add image in `COL-MD-4` to be on left side of container, but left edge of image to be outside container to edge of screen. This is an example [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTCn4.png)

**HTML**

```
<div class="aboutus">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 text pull-right">
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <p>Text Text text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.aboutus {
  margin-top: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #23BBEC;
}

.aboutus > div > div > .text {
  color: #FFF;
}

.aboutus > div > div > .text > h4 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
}

.aboutus > div > div > .text > p {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a pseudo-element is needed here.

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/BjqGEd)

```css
.aboutus {
  margin-top: 80px;
  background-color: #23BBEC;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.aboutus > .container > .row > .text {
  color: #FFF;
}
.aboutus > .container > .row > .text h4 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
}
.aboutus > .container > .row > .text > p {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.right {
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
}
.right::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 25px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50vw;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="aboutus">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 text pull-right right">
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <p>Text Text text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats it, but how to set element instead of pseudo-element? I need to make it responsive.

Comment: Oh....you want an *actual* element...that's a different question and one not represented by the code you provided.

Comment: I need to add slider instead background image.

Comment: Then you need to ask a proper **clear** question with the full code.